# C linked list access problems

Tags: c, linked-list

I've got a linked list that seems to work quite well. I am now trying to access it from a different method and this is where it gets problematic. I have a function that takes in a product ID and searches the list for it. If it's found then the whole node is returned. This is what it looks like:

```
struct product* searchForProduct(int * id){

  struct product *pProductIterator = pFirstNode;

  while(pProductIterator != NULL){

    int areTheyEqual;

    if(pProductIterator->id == id){
      areTheyEqual = 0;
    }
    else{
      areTheyEqual = 1;
    }

    if(areTheyEqual == 0){
      printf("Item %d : costs  %f",
             pProductIterator->id, 
             pProductIterator->price);

      return pProductIterator;
    }

    pProductBeforeProductToDelete = pProductIterator;
    pProductIterator = pProductIterator->next;
  }

  printf("%d wasn't found\n\n", id);

  return NULL;
}
```

The above code works fine in the sense that it will search and print out if the item has been found or not. But what I am struggling with is getting the returned node to work. I am trying to call something like this:

```
int z = 5;
itemprice = searchForProduct(z)->price;
```

What I'm trying to do is find item `z` (id `5`), take its value of `price` and save it into the variable `itemprice`. However what I get is this:

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

warning: passing argument 1 of 'searchForProduct' makes pointer from
integer without a cast
```

I've no idea what this means and so any ideas would be very appreciated here.

Comment: Function `searchForProduct` should take `int id`, not `int* id`. Not only because of the compilation error (which you can also solve by casting), but also because you're using `"%d"` in order to print it!!!

Comment: Why is the type of `id` `int *`? I should be `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//Actually declare the structure of the struct. This is why you get an incomplete type error.
//I've added the minimum number of members mentioned in your code.
struct product {
   int id;
   float price;
};


struct product* searchForProduct(int id){ //Not int*. No need to pass a pointer id isn't a array or structure or modifiable.

  struct product *pProductIterator = pFirstNode;

  while(pProductIterator != NULL){

    int areTheyEqual;

    if(pProductIterator->id == id){
      areTheyEqual = 1; //The universal convention (including C) is that 0 is false, everything else is true.
    }
    else{
      areTheyEqual = 0; //They are not equal.
    }

    if(areTheyEqual){//As stated C interprets 0 as 'false' and everything else 'true'. 
      printf("Item %d : costs  %f",  
             pProductIterator->id, 
             pProductIterator->price);

      return pProductIterator;
    }

    //pProductBeforeProductToDelete = pProductIterator; //Code removed. Doing nothing...
    pProductIterator = pProductIterator->next;
  }

  printf("%d wasn't found\n\n", id);

  return NULL;
}
```

Also do something like:

```
int z = 5;
struct product *item=searchForProduct(z);
if(item!=NULL){
    itemprice=item->price;
}else{
    //Do something about not finding the product here!
    itemprice=0.0;//Might be a good start....
}
```

Your version

```
searchForProduct(z)->price;
```

dereferences a `NULL` pointer when the product is unfound. It has totally undefined behaviour though probably crashes the whole program. It's the bane of every C programmers life and you should get in the habit of dealing with it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In your function prototype,

```
 struct product* searchForProduct(int * id);
```

id should not be declared as a pointer, the definition should be

```
 struct product* searchForProduct(int id);
```